# How to import using a path that is a variable in Python

Tags: python, import, directory, operating-system, sys

I am trying to make a program that will go through and visit an array of directories and run a program and create a file inside.

I have everything working except that I need to figure out a way to import from a new path each time to get to a new directory.

For example:

```
L =["directory1", "directory2", "directory3"]
for i in range(len(L)):
   #I know this is wrong, but just to give an idea
   myPath = "parent."+L[i]
   from myPath import file
   #make file... etc.
```

Obviously when I use myPath as a variable for the path to import, I get an error. I have tried several different ways by searching online through Stack Overflow and reading OS and Sys documentation, but have come to no working result.

Comment: Have you tried the `os.path` module?

Comment: What do you mean by "visit an array of directories and run a program and create a file inside."? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: For example, I want to create a text file inside each directory. To do this I must cycle through my array and take each directory name so I can visit it.

Comment: Hi there. Once an experienced editor has amended your post, please do not revert it unless the technical meaning of your question has been changed. You've reverted to a version containing errors and unnecessary instructions on how to use the site, so I will be reverting to the last good version. If you have objections please ping me with `@halfer` and we can involve a moderator. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 'imp' module to load source code of python scrips

```
import imp
root_dir = '/root/'
dirs =["directory1", "directory2", "directory3"]

for _dir in dirs:
    module_path = os.path.join(root_dir,_dir,'module.py')

    mod = imp.load_source("module_name", module_path)

    # now you can call function in regular way, like mod.some_func()
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a text file inside each directory. To do this I must
>   cycle through my array and take each directory name so I can visit it.

`import` is for loading external modules, not creating new files, if creating new files is what you want to do, use the `open` statement, and open the not yet existing file with `'w'` mode. Note: the directory must exist.

```
from os.path import join 
L =["directory1", "directory2", "directory3"]
for d in L: # loop through the directories 
    with open(join(d,"filename.txt"), "w") as file:
         pass # or do stuff with the newly created file
```

Comment: I know that import is not used to create new files. My program itself is going to do that, but I already have that part written. I just need to import a module from a file inside a directory and then create a new file inside. Sorry i definitely wasn't clear on that, just realized that now.